# Influence of active area of photo diode on sensitivity

Tags: photodiode, laser, laser-diode, sensitivity, photonics

I am using a photodiode for detecting the laser. I have a question regarding the active area of the photodiode.

Is smaller active area photodiode less sensitive? Or it totally depends on the laser spot- if the active area is sufficient enough to capture the spot of the laser, then active area greater than this won't affect or increase the sensitivity of the photodiode. please share your knowledge.

Comment: this makes no sense `Is less active area photodiode is less sensitive?`

Comment: I apologize for this silly question but I am new in this please correct me and give your thoughts regarding this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, you should be sure you understand the difference between responsivity and sensitivity.

Responsivity is the ratio of the photodetector current to the light impinging on it. The responsivity is given by

$${\mathcal R}=\frac{\eta e P}{h \nu}$$

where \$e\$ is the fundamental charge constant (the magnitude of the charge on an electron), \$P\$ is the optical power falling on the photodiode, \$h\$ is Planck's constant, and \$\nu\$ is the optical frequency (\$h\nu\$ is the energy per photon). The last term, \$\eta\$, is the *quantum efficiency*, essentially a catch-all term indicating what fraction of the photons reaching the photodiode actually produce current carriers.

Sensitivity, on the other hand, is the minimum amount of light that must be applied to the photodetector to produce a current distinguishable from noise. It's usually specified as a current equal to the noise or *dark current* of the photodetector (in which case it's often called *noise equivalent power* or NEP instead of sensitivity). In a receiver for an optical communications system, the sensitivity is usually specified as the minimum signal power required to achieve a certain bit error rate (BER) such as \$10^{-9}\$ or \$10^{-15}\$. Note that **lower** sensitivity is preferable to **higher** sensitivity: It's better to be able to detect a 1 nW signal than a 1 mW signal.

Now, responsivity does not depend on the photodiode area. However it will be more difficult to focus a spot from your source onto a smaller detector.

As for sensitivity, a larger photodiode will, all else being equal, have greater leakage current, and therefore poorer sensitivity. It will also have higher capacitance and therefore lower bandwidth, in case you're using it in a commnunications application.

Comment: Thanks for your valuable answer, I knew the responsivity but not clear about sensitivity. I will read some more articles regarding this and come here again if finds any query.

Comment: I didn't get the point of lower sensitivity vs higher sensitivity. Please suggest some good links where I can find a good knowledge regarding laser and photodiode with in-depth explanation.

Comment: If I say the sensitivity of some photodiode is 1 nW, that's very good. It means I can distinguish a 1 nW signal from noise. If I say the sensitivity of some other pd is 1 W, that's horrible. It means it needs a full 1 W optical signal to be able to distinguish it from noise. The point is to be careful when talking about "higher" and "lower" sensitivity, it's easy to say the wrong thing (or for others to misunderstand you). Better to talk about "better" and "worse" sensitivity.

Comment: I got the point. :-) Now this topic seems more interesting to me.  I will do some more research and experiment on this, want to gain more knowledge on this.

Answer (score 0):

> Is smaller active area photodiode less sensitive?

The active area of a photodiode is usually pretty small, usually much smaller than the bean width on your typical laser diode + collimator.  In a typical case the laser is hitting the entire active area rather than just a portion of it.  In that case (and all other things being equal) having a larger active area will produce more output current.

> Or it totally depends on the laser spot- if the active area is
> sufficient enough to capture the spot of the laser, then active area
> greater than this won't affect or increase the sensitivity of the
> photodiode.

Each part of the active area produces current proportional to the light hitting it.  If you actually had an active area larger than the laser beam then, the extra active area which is not being hit by the beam is not affected by it.  But that additional active area is picking up ambient light so it's increasing the noise in your system (in which case it's better not to have it).

It should be noted that one can tune the size of the active area by adjusting the reverse voltage on the photodiode (more voltage increases area).